# What should I do if I get email about my account claiming to be from Apple?

Tags: apple-id

For about a week now I keep getting an SMS giving me an Apple ID verification code. It will do it a couple of times and then a phone call. Today I received this email:

> Subject: Verify your Apple ID before We closed Your account.
>
> Dear Apple User,
>
> We unable verify your account informations in order to continue using your Apple. 
>   This Apple ID has been locked for security reasons. 
>   You must unlock your account to continue using your Apple ID.
>
> To read your secure message by opening the attachment (PDF). 
>   You will be prompted to open (view) the file or save (download) it to your computer.
>
> For best result, Save the file first, then open it on a web browser.
>
> Your account will be disabled if we didn't receive any response from you in more than twenty four hours
>
> Sincerly 
>   Apple Support

The whole thing sounds fishy to me. Or phishing to me.

What I am needing to know is, is this a real email from them or no? It just seems off.

Comment: You can tell from the grammatical errors alone that it is not an official email form Apple Support!

Comment: That is exactly what I thought as well. But my husband wasn't as convinced and wanted me to get advice.

Comment: Just seems odd that I have been getting the SMS for the codes and now this email. The newest SMS was 4:20am est. sound asleep and here are these texts and phone calls.

Comment: I would send them a "Timeline Inverter™" and some kind of "Reverse Grammar Bomb™"...

Comment: All the answers provided are correct, but I wanted to re-emphasise the comment by @user3439894 - grammatical errors are a definite tell-tale sign for this type of thing. Apple uses a _style guide_ for all their comms and they are __very strict__ about it. In addition to punctuation, spelling, grammar, formatting, etc they use pre-approved _scripts_ for their automated comms and these definitely do not have any of the obvious errors found in the email you received.

Comment: Just the misspelling of *[sincerely](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sincerely#Adverb)* (*sincerly*) gives it away.

Comment: If you have two-factor auth enabled the repeated SMSs may indicate that someone has your password.

Answer (score 14):

Apple has a support page regarding phishing attempts, see [Identify and report phishing emails and other suspicious messages](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204759). Taken from there:

> These are common signs of a possible phishing attempt:
>
> - The sender’s email address doesn’t match the name of the company that it claims to be from.
> - The message was sent to an email address or phone number that's different from the one that you gave that company.
> - A link appears to be legitimate but takes you to a website whose URL doesn’t match the address of the company’s website.
> - The message starts with a generic greeting, like “Dear valued customer” — most legitimate companies will include your name in their messages to you.
> - The message looks significantly different from other messages that you’ve received from the company.
> - The message requests personal information, like a credit card number or account password.
> - The message is unsolicited and contains an attachment.

It also recommends to report such messages to Apple by using "Forward As Attachment" within Mail and then send it to `reportphishing@apple.com`.

Answer (score 6):

This is phishing and/or malware. Apple do not send emails like this. You're not being "hacked", but rather just a phishing/malware attempt in an email. You should not download the attachment.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a phishing attack. Do not follow the instructions. PDFs have been known to contain many security vulnerabilities, so they aren't ever used for secure authentication operations, such as "recovering your account".

Moreover all Apple ID operations should be done through the verified Apple website.

Block the sender.

Comment: "they aren't ever used for secure authentication operations" unfortunately, that just isn't true (unless i've misunderstood you). US universities and insurance companies are infamous for using PDFs to communicate sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i had the same problem all i did was clicked underneath the email adress tracked the IP found out where it was being sent from and then contacted the local Phishing police in that area if not just contact some sort of online help guide.

I got another one from the same people a week later it turned out to be the same IP so ignored it, only click the link, speak to apple, give details if they have *Proof* that they are the official company/person if not dont listen to them as they are bad

Comment: This doesn't really cover new ground. Be sure to vote up the other answer that explains this is social engineering / attempts to compromise your accounts and systems.